# Multivariate Gaussian integral over the complex plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I'm trying to prove the following claim:

$$\intop\prod_k\frac{dx_kdx_k^*}{2\pi i}e^{-x_kH_{kj}x_j+x_kJ_k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|\det H|}}e^{J_k^*H^{-1}_{kj}J_j}$$

when the integral is taken over the complex plane, and H is hermitian (is this true for non-hermitian matrices was well?).
I'm not really sure how to approach this, what does $dx_idx_i^*$ even mean? Is this a complex surface element? Is the result a number or an operator or an exponent of a vector? (I'm a physics student, so the exponent probably assumes Einstien notation).

Comment: Are you sure the denominator is $2\pi i$? It's just that in complex analysis one sees quite a lot of $2\pi i$, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$. However, in your expression it's an index in the product...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it the imaginary number and not the index.

Comment: If it's the imaginary unit, then you might want to change the index of the product. Could be confusing. Have you checked the source of the problem?

Comment: I changed the index to make the formula more clear

Comment: Is $H$ hermitian matrix? It can simplify the integral if you transform basis.

Comment: @eranreches I think we can assume $H$ is hermitian

Comment: can someone help?